# Display dynamic HTML as tab content in Angular UI

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/EoBBrRuus7UUXIUROmrp?p=preview) I have a Angular UI tabs with HTML content that needs to be generated dynamically. Still, the tab contents shows instead the HTML markup. How to fix this?

HTML

```
 <uib-tabset>
    <uib-tab index="$index + 1" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}">
      {{tab.content}}
    </uib-tab>
 </uib-tabset>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('ctl', function ($scope) {

     $scope.tabs = [
                    { title:'title 1', content:'<div id="id1">111</div>' },
                    { title:'title 2', content:'<div id="id2">222</div>' }
                  ];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<div ng-bind-html="tab.content"></div>` :

```
 <uib-tabset>
    <uib-tab index="$index + 1" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}">
      <div ng-bind-html="tab.content"></div>
    </uib-tab>
  </uib-tabset>
```